# Hyphen not indexing in Sphinx even though not in stopwords, charset, ignore_chars

Tags: sphinx

My searches consistently match 'A-B' to 'A B'. I do not have a charset_table in the config, nor a ignore_chars. I have a small stopwords but for 'the in and of'.

Where is Sphinx being told to ignore -? I am trying to make it recognize it so I can force behavior with regexp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-` is not in the default `cherset_table` - the documentation says what the default is, but it basically just includes A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _.

`rexexp_filter` are run before charset_table processing, so can be used to change behaviour of - regardless of the charset_table.